# having trouble getting base64 string to ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

I have an image that is encoded in base64, I'm trying to get it to a controller but no matter what I try, the parameter always comes in null.

I'm using angular's `$http` service;

```
$http.post('url', base64string);
```

And I'm trying to pass it through a controller...

```
[HttpPost("submit/image")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitImageData(byte[] data) {
      // ...
}
```

I can see that the data is clearly going in my request header in Chrome. But I can't figure out what data type it needs. `string` doesn't work. `IFormFile` doesn't work. I just can't seem to get the damn information to the controller.

I know the route is right. If I put a debug breakpoint, it hits it. But `data` is always `null` no matter what data type I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS code should look something like this:

```
$http.post('url', { data: base64string });
```

and the declaration of your controller's method should be:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitImageData(string data) {
```

**EDIT**

Try adding the [FromBody] attribute:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitImageData([FromBody] string data) {
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It still comes in as null.

Comment: I know the base64 string is good. I can render it as an image just fine.

Comment: I can also see the string in the `Request Payload` part of the debugging tools. I know it is being sent.

Comment: Check the library [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Comment: I'm not looking to upload a file object. I need to send what I already have to the server.

Comment: Add the [FromBody] attribute before the method's parameter.

Comment: It's just a string, kagelos' solution should work, even without [FromBody].
Maybe if you remove "submit/image" form your httppost attribute, it works.

Comment: String or not, if it's POSTed you need the attribute, otherwise it's being looked up in the query string.

Comment: I have made progress. If I change the type from `string` to `dynamic`, the data makes it to the controller. Now I just need to figure out the exact type it's truly expecting.

Comment: I found the problem. The issue was that the actual data being passed was both a parameter, but the string itself is on a property of the object. Since I was only expecting a string, it came through null. But passing in `data.data` sent the actual string.

Comment: well, now I'm pulling my hair out because I can't get `Convert.FromBase64String` to work with the data passed.

Comment: what is the solution for this?